# JQuery.when() and then() not working with asynchronous event

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I'm trying to read lines from a text file, choose one line from the file and insert it to a div on html page.

```
var chosenWord="original word";

function wordFromFile(fileName) {
    $.get(fileName, function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        var lineCount = lines.length;
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((lineCount-1) + 1));
        var word = lines[randomIndex];
        window.chosenWord = word;
        console.log("wordFromFile: "+chosenWord);
    });
}

function setRandomWord() {
  $.when(wordFromFile("http://mypage.com/words.txt")).then(appendWord());
}

function appendWord() {
  console.log("appendWord: "+window.chosenWord);
  $('.word').text(window.chosenWord);
}

$(function() {
  if($('body').is('.playpage')) {
    setRandomWord();
  }

});


console shows:
appendWord: original word
wordFromFile: particle //when i refresh the page this word changes but appendWord is always "original word"
```

How can I make it so that function wordFromFile(fileName) is completed first and appendWord gets the same value for global variable chosenWord? I don't understand why when() and then() functions don't work in my code.

Comment: wordFromFile does not return a Promise, in fact it doesn't return anything - $.when works with Promises, not `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the promise in `wordFromFile()`.

```
function wordFromFile(fileName) {
    return $.get(fileName).then(function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        var lineCount = lines.length;
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * lineCount);
        var word = lines[randomIndex];
        window.chosenWord = word;
        console.log("wordFromFile: "+chosenWord);
        return chosenWord;
    });
}
```

And, if you want your final `chosenWord` value to be the resolved value of the promise, then you should return it from the `.then()` handler.  Also, notice that I changed your callback on `$.get()` to a `.then()` handler to make things a lot more consistent.  In general, once you're using promises, you want to use them consistently within an operation and not mix old-fashioned callbacks within promises.  Doing so defeats some of the automatic error propagation and error handling features that promises provide.

Then, you don't need to use `$.when()` at all in `setRandomWord()` because `wordFromFile()` already returns a promise and you need to pass a function reference to `.then()` without the parens after appendWord:

```
function setRandomWord() {
  wordFromFile("http://mypage.com/words.txt").then(appendWord);
}
```

To recap:

1. Return the promise from `wordFromFile()`
2. Use a `.then()` handler inside of `wordFromFile()` rather than the jQuery callback.
3. Remove `$.when()` around `wordFromFile()` as it isn't needed.
4. Remove parens after `appendWord` when passing a function reference to `.then()`.  The way you had it was calling appendWord immediately rather than allowing the `.then()` handler to call it sometime later when the promise resolves.
5. Your random number logic was not quite right unless you were always trying to avoid the first word.

Keep in mind that promises do not have magic powers.  They do not "know" when an asynchronous operation inside of them is somehow done.  They only know when an async operation is done when that async operation manually resolves the promise.  So, you can't just put some async operation inside a `$.when()` and expect `$.when()` to magically know when that async operation is done (lots of people try this so apparently it is something that people new to promises seem to expect).  Instead, you pass promises to `$.when()` and the async operations must resolve those promises.  In your case, you only have one promise so there is no need for `$.when()`.  It is generally only needed when you have more than one promise you want to wait for.  When you just have one promise, you can just call `.then()` on it.

Other things to note:

1. You're using a global variable `chosenWord` to communicate back the results.  That is not necessary and is generally considered an anti-pattern.
2. You don't have any error handling on your ajax call.

This code:

```
$(function() {
  if($('body').is('.playpage')) {
    setRandomWord();
  }

});
```

could be simplified to this:

```
$(function() {
  $("body.playpage").each(setRandomWord);
});
```

If the body tag has a `playpage` class on it, then it will call `setRandomWord()`.  If not, it will not call it.

---

You could remove the `chosenWord` global from your code like this:

```
function wordFromFile(fileName) {
    return $.get(fileName).then(function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
        var word = lines[randomIndex];
        console.log("wordFromFile: "+word);
        return word;
    });
}


function setRandomWord() {
  return wordFromFile("http://mypage.com/words.txt")).then(appendWord);
}

function appendWord(word) {
  console.log("appendWord: "+word);
  $('.word').text(word);
}

$(function() {
  $("body.playpage").each(setRandomWord);
});
```

Here the chosen word is made the resolved value of the promise that `wordFromFile()` returns so it will be passed to any `.then()` handler off that promise.  When you pass `appendWord` as a `.then()` handler, that means that the word will be passed to `appendWord` for you.  And, wala no global is used.

Comment: @Prosper - Since it looks like you may be new here, when you get your question answered, you should select the best answer by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer.  That both indicates to the community that your question has been answered and it earns you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.